# vba excel counta

Tags: vba, reference, count, excel

```
Cells(4, x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(Workbooks(""DB_Report.xls"").Sheets(x).Range(A:A))
```

I am trying to get the above function to work.

I am calling the script from the workbook `DB_report.xls`

This creates a new workbook ("month") and starts filling in the values.

What I am trying to get to is where

cell `4,1` in months has the counta of sheet 1 from DB_report

cell `4,2` in months has the counta of sheet 2 from DB_report

Can anyone reword the line above so when "months is the active work sheet I can call counta from DB_Report

The line before this is

```
NameSH = Workbooks("DB_Report.xls").Sheets(x).Name and this works fine and returns the name of work sheet x
```

Thanks

Aaron

Ok for a bit further explicanation

the steps I want to do go some thing like this

select workbook months.xls
select sheet(1)
cell (x,y)  = counta( of range A:A , in worksheet("DB_Report") of worksheet (DB_report.xls)

Now I know

Cells(4, x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(sheet(3).range(a:A)

will work with in the active work sheet. So if the active sheet is sheet 1 then that would count up he numbe of cells in sheet 3 of the same workbook. I wanted to know if as well as refrenced sheet and cells in the function I can also refrence a workbook by name.

of course i could swqap to book "DB_Report" save the value to a varible and then swap back to book "Month" and copy it to the cell.

or could I do workbook("month").sheet(y).cells(a,b) = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(sheet(3).range(a:A)

while in workbook "month"

so really what i need is how do you refrence workbook,sheet and cells all with in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Cheers for the comments, but i finaly worked out what the problem was.

it was simple really I was just missing some formatting

the line below works correctly

```
cell(x,y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("DB_Report.xls").Sheets(x).Range("A:A"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you were trying to do, but it comes close and is a bit more generalized.  It counts up the worksheets in what would be `DB_Report.xls` and uses that to specify that number of cells in `months.xls`

If you are running the macro from the `DB_Report.xls` you don't need to specify anything about that workbook or sheets.

```
Sub counts()
    Dim sheetcounts As Integer
    Dim countas() As Integer
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim newbook As Workbook

    sheetcounts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim countas(sheetcounts)

    For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        countas(index) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wksht.Range("A:A"))
        index = index + 1
    Next

    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
    newbook.Activate
    newbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, sheetcounts)) = countas
    newbook.SaveAs ("months.xls")

End Sub
```

It will require any error checking or verification that you need to put into it.